# Regexp to remove nested parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, parentheses

I've been stuck trying to write a regular expression in Java to remove everything in the parenthesis below while preserving everything else.  **Note that the parenthesis can be nested, and I think this is why my pattern fails**.  Can someone help me?  Below I tried:

```
    String testData =
            "1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. Nf3 O-O 6. Be2 e5 7. dxe5 dxe5 8. Qxd8 Rxd8 9. Bg5 Nbd7 10. O-O-O {Diagram [#]} " +
            "Rf8 (10... Re8 11. Nb5 (11. Nd5)) (10... h6 11. Bxf6 Bxf6 12. Nd5) 11. Nd5 c6 (11... Nxe4 12. Nxc7 Rb8 13. Be3 b6 ) 12. Ne7+ Kh8 13. " +
            "Nxc8 Raxc8 14. Bxf6 (14. Be3) 14... Nxf6 15. Nd2 (15. Bd3) 15... Bh6 16. f3 Nd7 17. Kc2 Bxd2 (17... Rcd8 18. b4) 18. Rxd2 Nc5 19. b4 Ne6 20. Rd7 b5 " +
            "(20... Rcd8 21. Rxb7 Nd4+ 22. Kd3) 21. Rxa7 Nd4+ 22. Kd3 Rcd8 23. Ke3 Nc2+ 24. Kf2 Rd2 25. Rd1 Rfd8 26. Rxd2 {Diagram [#]} (26. cxb5 cxb5 " +
            "27. Rc7 Rxd1 28. Bxd1 Rd2+ 29. Kg3 Ne1 30. Bb3 f6 31. Rf7 Nxg2 32. Rf8+ Kg7 33. Rf7+ Kh6 34. Rxf6 Nf4 35. Kh4 (35. Rxf4 exf4+ 36. Kxf4 Rxh2) 35... " +
            "Rxh2+ 36. Kg4 Rg2+ 37. Kh4 Nd3 38. a3 Rh2+ 39. Kg4 Rh1 40. Rc6 {Diagram [#]}) 26... Rxd2 27. Kf1 Nd4 28. cxb5 cxb5 29. a4 (29. Rd7 Rxa2 30. Bd3 Ra3 31. " +
            "Be2 Ra1+ 32. Kf2 Ra2 ) (29. Bxb5 Nxb5) 29... Rxe2 (29... bxa4 30. Bc4) 30. axb5 Rb2 31. b6 Rxb4 32. b7 Kg7  ";


    testData = testData.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("{") + ".*" + Pattern.quote("}"), "")
                    .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("(") + ".*" + Pattern.quote(")"), "")
                    .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$") + "[0-9]+", "");

    System.out.println(testData);
```

but this prints:

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. Nf3 O-O 6. Be2 e5 7. dxe5 dxe5 8. Qxd8 Rxd8 9. Bg5 Nbd7 10. O-O-O  Rf8 )  11. Nd5 c6  12. Ne7+ Kh8 13. Nxc8 Raxc8 14. Bxf6  14... Nxf6 15. Nd2  15... Bh6 16. f3 Nd7 17. Kc2 Bxd2  18. Rxd2 Nc5 19. b4 Ne6 20. Rd7 b5  21. Rxa7 Nd4+ 22. Kd3 Rcd8 23. Ke3 Nc2+ 24. Kf2 Rd2 25. Rd1 Rfd8 26. Rxd2   35... Rxh2+ 36. Kg4 Rg2+ 37. Kh4 Nd3 38. a3 Rh2+ 39. Kg4 Rh1 40. Rc6 ) 26... Rxd2 27. Kf1 Nd4 28. cxb5 cxb5 29. a4   29... Rxe2  30. axb5 Rb2 31. b6 Rxb4 32. b7 Kg7

which is obviously wrong because it has parenthesis in it.

The correct answer would be:

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. Nf3 O-O 6. Be2 e5 7. dxe5 dxe5 8. Qxd8 Rxd8 9. Bg5 Nbd7 10. O-O-O  Rf8   11. Nd5 c6  12. Ne7+ Kh8 13. Nxc8 Raxc8 14. Bxf6  14... Nxf6 15. Nd2  15... Bh6 16. f3 Nd7 17. Kc2 Bxd2  18. Rxd2 Nc5 19. b4 Ne6 20. Rd7 b5  21. Rxa7 Nd4+ 22. Kd3 Rcd8 23. Ke3 Nc2+ 24. Kf2 Rd2 25. Rd1 Rfd8 26. Rxd2   26... Rxd2 27. Kf1 Nd4 28. cxb5 cxb5 29. a4   29... Rxe2  30. axb5 Rb2 31. b6 Rxb4 32. b7 Kg7

Comment: Is the number of opening braces/parenthesis/brackets equal to the number of closing ones?

Comment: yes, it is from the PGN spec

Comment: I suppose that this isn't a regular language anymore. It more looks like a Chomsky-2 language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) - as one needs to count the parentheses which were opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regex here. As you could see from your example something like `\\(.*?)\\)` would try to find minimal match between first founded `(` and next `)` so in case of data like

```
a (b (c d) e) f
```

regex `\(.*?\)` will match

```
a (b (c d) e) f
  ^^^^^^^^
```

and will leave `e)` part unmatched.

You probably could write regex for this task because some regex flavors support recursion, but unfortunately regex engine used in Java doesn't.

So to remove nested bracket you can write your own simple parser, like
<sub>(I assume that text is well formatted so there are no such things like `({)}` or unclosed bracket)</sub>

```
String data = "1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. Nf3 O-O 6. Be2 e5 7. dxe5 dxe5 8. Qxd8 Rxd8 9. Bg5 Nbd7 10. O-O-O {Diagram [#]} "
        + "Rf8 (10... Re8 11. Nb5 (11. Nd5)) (10... h6 11. Bxf6 Bxf6 12. Nd5) 11. Nd5 c6 (11... Nxe4 12. Nxc7 Rb8 13. Be3 b6 ) 12. Ne7+ Kh8 13. "
        + "Nxc8 Raxc8 14. Bxf6 (14. Be3) 14... Nxf6 15. Nd2 (15. Bd3) 15... Bh6 16. f3 Nd7 17. Kc2 Bxd2 (17... Rcd8 18. b4) 18. Rxd2 Nc5 19. b4 Ne6 20. Rd7 b5 "
        + "(20... Rcd8 21. Rxb7 Nd4+ 22. Kd3) 21. Rxa7 Nd4+ 22. Kd3 Rcd8 23. Ke3 Nc2+ 24. Kf2 Rd2 25. Rd1 Rfd8 26. Rxd2 {Diagram [#]} (26. cxb5 cxb5 "
        + "27. Rc7 Rxd1 28. Bxd1 Rd2+ 29. Kg3 Ne1 30. Bb3 f6 31. Rf7 Nxg2 32. Rf8+ Kg7 33. Rf7+ Kh6 34. Rxf6 Nf4 35. Kh4 (35. Rxf4 exf4+ 36. Kxf4 Rxh2) 35... "
        + "Rxh2+ 36. Kg4 Rg2+ 37. Kh4 Nd3 38. a3 Rh2+ 39. Kg4 Rh1 40. Rc6 {Diagram [#]}) 26... Rxd2 27. Kf1 Nd4 28. cxb5 cxb5 29. a4 (29. Rd7 Rxa2 30. Bd3 Ra3 31. "
        + "Be2 Ra1+ 32. Kf2 Ra2 ) (29. Bxb5 Nxb5) 29... Rxe2 (29... bxa4 30. Bc4) 30. axb5 Rb2 31. b6 Rxb4 32. b7 Kg7  ";

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

int parenthesisCounter = 0;

for (char c : data.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '(' || c == '{' )
        parenthesisCounter++;
    if (c == ')' || c == '}' )
        parenthesisCounter--;
    if (!(c == '(' || c == '{' || c == ')' || c == '}') && parenthesisCounter == 0)
        buffer.append(c);
}
```

And after that you can just focus on removing rest of unwanted data like you used before

```
.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$") + "[0-9]+", "");
```

so result of

```
System.out.println(buffer.toString().replaceAll(
        Pattern.quote("$") + "[0-9]+", ""));
```

will be

> `1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. Nf3 O-O 6. Be2 e5 7. dxe5 dxe5 8. Qxd8 Rxd8 9. Bg5 Nbd7 10. O-O-O  Rf8   11. Nd5 c6  12. Ne7+ Kh8 13. Nxc8 Raxc8 14. Bxf6  14... Nxf6 15. Nd2  15... Bh6 16. f3 Nd7 17. Kc2 Bxd2  18. Rxd2 Nc5 19. b4 Ne6 20. Rd7 b5  21. Rxa7 Nd4+ 22. Kd3 Rcd8 23. Ke3 Nc2+ 24. Kf2 Rd2 25. Rd1 Rfd8 26. Rxd2   26... Rxd2 27. Kf1 Nd4 28. cxb5 cxb5 29. a4   29... Rxe2  30. axb5 Rb2 31. b6 Rxb4 32. b7 Kg7`

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Can you provide an explanation as to why the regular expression fails?

Comment: @AmirAfghani Because standard regular expressions aren't powerful enough for arbitrary depth nested parantheses. You *might* be able to do it with extensions, but a standard regex isn't good enough. This is because the computational power of a regex is only enough for a regular language, not a context free language like nested brackets (formalised as the Dyck language).

Comment: The explanation is simple. Java regexes doesn't handle recursive subpatterns (Java regexes doesn't have the recursion feature as Perl, PHP, Ruby, R...)). A way to do it with regexes is to find the innermost content inside parenthesis that is preceded with an opening parenthesis (without a closing parenthesis character) in a while loop.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipWhitehouse.  Also, I I think the answer provided isn't completely right.  I want to remove everything WITHIN the parens and the PARENS.  I get the gist of the answer though.

Comment: @AmirAfghani may I know the expected result above?

Answer (score 2):

Pshemo's answer is good, but I wanted to show you how it could be done using regular expressions and how I think the parsing can be optimized:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created for http://stackoverflow.com/a/25335225/1266906
 */
public class RemoveBrackets {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testData =
                "1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7 4. e4 d6 5. Nf3 O-O 6. Be2 e5 7. dxe5 dxe5 8. Qxd8 Rxd8 9. Bg5 Nbd7 10. O-O-O {Diagram [#]} " +
                        "Rf8 (10... Re8 11. Nb5 (11. Nd5)) (10... h6 11. Bxf6 Bxf6 12. Nd5) 11. Nd5 c6 (11... Nxe4 12. Nxc7 Rb8 13. Be3 b6 ) 12. Ne7+ Kh8 13. " +
                        "Nxc8 Raxc8 14. Bxf6 (14. Be3) 14... Nxf6 15. Nd2 (15. Bd3) 15... Bh6 16. f3 Nd7 17. Kc2 Bxd2 (17... Rcd8 18. b4) 18. Rxd2 Nc5 19. b4 Ne6 20. Rd7 b5 " +
                        "(20... Rcd8 21. Rxb7 Nd4+ 22. Kd3) 21. Rxa7 Nd4+ 22. Kd3 Rcd8 23. Ke3 Nc2+ 24. Kf2 Rd2 25. Rd1 Rfd8 26. Rxd2 {Diagram [#]} (26. cxb5 cxb5 " +
                        "27. Rc7 Rxd1 28. Bxd1 Rd2+ 29. Kg3 Ne1 30. Bb3 f6 31. Rf7 Nxg2 32. Rf8+ Kg7 33. Rf7+ Kh6 34. Rxf6 Nf4 35. Kh4 (35. Rxf4 exf4+ 36. Kxf4 Rxh2) 35... " +
                        "Rxh2+ 36. Kg4 Rg2+ 37. Kh4 Nd3 38. a3 Rh2+ 39. Kg4 Rh1 40. Rc6 {Diagram [#]}) 26... Rxd2 27. Kf1 Nd4 28. cxb5 cxb5 29. a4 (29. Rd7 Rxa2 30. Bd3 Ra3 31. " +
                        "Be2 Ra1+ 32. Kf2 Ra2 ) (29. Bxb5 Nxb5) 29... Rxe2 (29... bxa4 30. Bc4) 30. axb5 Rb2 31. b6 Rxb4 32. b7 Kg7  ";
        System.out.println(replaceLoop(testData).replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$") + "[0-9]+", ""));
        System.out.println(copyIterator(testData).replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$") + "[0-9]+", ""));
    }

    private static String replaceLoop(String data) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\([^()]*\\)|\\{[^{}]*\\}");
        String previous, current = data;
        do {
            previous = current;
            current = pattern.matcher(previous).replaceAll("");
        } while (!previous.equals(current));
        return current;
    }

    private static String copyIterator(String data) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int start = 0;
        int level = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            switch (data.charAt(i)) {
                case '(':
                case '{':
                    if (level == 0 && start >= 0) {
                        sb.append(data.substring(start, i));
                        start = -1;
                    }
                    level++;
                    break;
                case ')':
                case '}':
                    level--;
                    if (level == 0) {
                        start = i + 1;
                    } else if (level < 0) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Too many closing brackets.");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (level > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Too many opening brackets.");
        }
        if (start >= 0 && start < data.length()) {
            sb.append(data.substring(start, data.length()));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

In `replaceLoop` I remove only brace-groups which do not contain braces themselves (inner most braces) and therefore have to repeat until the `String` does no longer change. This can be expensive especially if you expect braces to be nested a lot. As previously stated the problem is that you can only refer to already matched characters, not to their opposite or their count; if you know how deep things are normally nested, you can of course write a pattern that will remove all expected levels at once and only seldomly require more than two searches.

In `copyIterator` I determine which chunks are not embraced and copy those chunks into a new `StringBuilder`. By copying chunks I minimize the number of times the `StringBuilder` resizes and as copying blocks is often equally expensive as copying single characters the cost per character decreases. Also by using `switch` the compiler can utilize an integer-map which can perform the check for the 4 relevant characters at once rather than checking them one by one as it would need to do when I do `if`s (yeah, cool compilers should do this for you, but ...).